# Get distance by road between two lat lng in android

Tags: java, android, distance, google-directions-api

I am creating a blood bank app in which I am showing the user, his current position and different donors available near him on a map. When the user clicks on the blood request button, I show him a list of different donors available near him. Now on the list with the names of donors, I want to show the distance of that donor from the user current location. Right now I am getting distance by line which always shows 56 KM less than the actual distance. For that I am doing this :

```
donarLat = profiles.getLatitude();
                donarLong = profiles.getLongitude();
                String distance = "";
                if (currentLat != null && currentLong != null && donarLat != null && donarLong != null) {

                    origin = new LatLng(currentLat, currentLong);
                    dest = new LatLng(donarLat, donarLong);
                    float[] result = new float[1];
//                    Location.distanceBetween(currentLat, currentLong,donarLat, donarLong, result);
                    distance = String.valueOf(SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween(origin,dest));
                    System.out.println("d9" + profiles.getName()+ " : " + distance);
```

I have also got the distance using Location as you can see the commented line in code but it all gives location by line but I want to get the Location by road for which I have seen a lot of answers on StackOverflow which was answered minimum 6 years ago and also tried but sometimes it crashes app or some times it does nothing. I assume that for location by the road, I have to use google direction API but how I don't understand how to use it. I have tried that API in postman but first, it gave me an error to enable direction API after doing that it asked me to enable billing method. I am attaching the photo of Postman. And will be really thankful if someone shows me how to use API properly to get the exact distance by road.
[image]

Comment: You have to enable billing for your application: [billing for google services](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158867?hl=en) , that is one of the reasons it seems to be crashing. Enable the billing and then let us know if you still need help.

Comment: but the tutorial I have seen they haven't done that or nor ask to do that thing
and I don't want to do that there should be some way to use it for free for testing or stuff like that

Comment: the tutorial is probably outdated then. regardless, if you want to get services from google, you'll have to enable billing and possibly register your application to generate an API key.

Comment: that's what Iam saying if Now we want to get the api key we have to register billing method for that but I have already generated API Key for 2 of my project 6 to 7 months back I think so and I am using those key which are working perfectly fine.So I thought for those API key there may b a method that I can use this for trial version or get some free QUOTA  for testing purpose

Comment: it's bad practice to use API keys from other projects, generally it should be a 1:1 ratio for API keys to projects. create a new project with google and register it for this blood bank app, generate its key and see the difference.

Comment: The key I am using at the moment is applied in only in this project and I forgot to mention that the project whose API key I am using is made a month ago by me

Comment: Have you used Google direction API? If yes can you show me a detail explanation for each step if possible coz I am feeling that there should be some other issue for old project we can still use a free QUOTA without billing method

Comment: okay, let's go with the fact that your POSTMAN return header on that error_message is stating 'You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Projects at ...', that's why I am skeptical and give you my recommendation to make a unique project and key for this unique application.

Comment: Ok give me 10 I am going to make a new project and API key,though the key I am using is also unique as Iam using it only in this project but lets make an other one and try that

Comment: OK I have created a new key and tried in POSTMAN but got the same error on the other hand I am getting the map fine in my app

Comment: can you post an output of what the console in your IDE is saying as well as what the results from postman?

Comment: In POSTMAN it showing me the same error as mentioned above in picture and getting nothing in logcat so I have removed all code at the moment I am getting location by line
And Want a code how to put a google direction API properly in project

Answer (score 0):

Google API is not `FREE` now

Some API is free for some period but charge cost after that trial period.
And they require an API key with billing info to use trial.

In your case you have to your API key is not valid.

Create an API key with billing info form [this link](https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/6158867?hl=en) and be sure you can use it for a trial period. If not you may get changed.

Comment: might want to bold that, now **NOT** free